# Warning for og:audio although secure_url is given

Tags: audio, facebook-opengraph

When I check in the Facebook og debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

this page (as an example)

https://www.bodalgo.com/en/voice-talents/joel-vasquez

I get this error:

> Share has playable media but will not play inline because it would cause a >mixed content warning if embedded. Add a secure_src or make the video src >secure to fix this.

But as you can check in the source, I provide a secure_url for the audio. Why does it not work?

Comment: do you have any updates on this? i also experience a similar problem

Comment: finally, for no specific reason if i declare the filename as an mpeg instead of mp3 all the issues go away..

Comment: mpetyx: Could you give an example, please? I am not sure I understand how you change the filename ...

Comment: I had to add `<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/mpeg">` instead of `<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/mp3">` in order to remove the errors.. does this help somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I already had "audio/mpeg". The error persists.